# Issue slipstreaming MOSS with SP2 for Windows Server R2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to slipstream SP2 into MOSS 2007 but when I run the installer I keep getting the same error (program is blocked).

I am going by this link - http://blogs.technet.com/seanearp/archive/2009/05/20/slipstreaming-sp2-into-sharepoint-server-2007.aspx . However, I have deleted all the sp1 files from the updates folder. Furthermore, I am not using any cumulative updates but just the sp2 for Office Servers/WSS.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Using [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261890.aspx) as a template, I was able to create my own slip-streamed install source. Reading the article you posted, I differed in that I used the package with SP1 included, and did not delete any of the SP1 files from my extracted source. I also included the Oct 2009 Cumulative Update. When performing my extracts, I extracted all files directly to the updates folder. Also, my test installation using the slipstreamed source was only on a Windows 2003R2. Haven't tried with server 2008 since was haven't upgraded any of our servers yet.

Comment: When you must have copied the iso and its contents to a local hd, did you burn that folder (with the iso's root and sub content) to dvd? How did you mount the iso back - with its mods? I'd like to do this the way someone who has succeeded has done it.

Comment: I used the installer package at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2E6E5A9C-EBF6-4F7F-8467-F4DE6BD6B831&displaylang=en, using the version that included SP1. I ran the installer with the /extract:<folder> command. I then ran SP2 and the October cumulative updates with /extract commands, extracting them directly to the /Updates folder. Finally deleted the Wsssetup.dll files from the /Updates folder. I then copied the whole folder into my testing virtual machine and ran it. No conversion back to an ISO and mounting necessary.

Comment: Hey... I wrote that post! :)  Did you ever get the slipstream up and running?